# Can Xcode 7 working in Hackintosh?

Tags: ios, xcode7, hackintosh

I want to study Swift to develop IOS apps. But I don't have a Mac computer. So Can I using hackintosh(10.10.4) instead of macintosh? and can Xcode 7 working in hackintosh? Have anyone tried it?

Comment: Have you tried following the tons of guides out there?

Comment: And note that you are probably violating the apple eula.

Comment: Yeah, I've googled it, but there're only about xcode 6. and I'm not sure about xcode 7, and thank You for your reminder about apple eula. I'll think about buy a real Mac machine.

Comment: So you did not *try* out any of those guides!?

Comment: Yeah. Actually, I even haven't installed hackintosh yet. :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it will run, but first you should install hackintosh in your pc then update the latest os from store. and install your Xcode7

Comment: Thanks. Have you tried this? Are there side effects? I'm worried it since I'm using niresh yosemite 10.10.0  and want to update bug fix to 10.10.5.

Comment: yes i've been using it since 1yr

Comment: Install _hackintosh_? How the heck do you install Hackintosh?